# Callback function in jquery getjson

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, callback

Is there a way to do the following:

```
var baseURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/";

reverseGeocode(latlng, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else if (res.error) {
            callback(res.error);
        } else {
            callback(null, findPostal(res.body));
        }
    });


function reverseGeocode(coords, callback) {
var query = {
    sensor: "false",
    latlng: coords[0] + "," + coords[1]
};

$.getJSON(baseURL + "geocode/json", query).done(callback);
}
```

The callback in the getJSON call always results with an in err.

Comment: Cross domain origin error maybe ? Use JSONP.

Comment: It works fine when I try it: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/j694g9n7/

Comment: The arguments to the call back are `( data, textStatus, jqXHR )`. Why are you expecting the first argument to be an error flag?